# Pass ScreenEdgePanGesture on UIWebView to parent PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I am embedding Google Maps for navigation in a full-width `UIWebView` that is itself embedded in a `UIPageViewController` (in scroll mode). The page controller responds to the page turn gesture on all pages, even inside the `UIWebView`, *unless* the `UIWebView` has Google Maps loaded. Obviously, this is because the web page has intercepted the pan/swipe gesture. I wish to allow all panning and interaction inside the web page except if the gesture is an edge swipe. A pan gesture near the edge is also acceptable if edge swiping is not possible.

I can add a `ScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` and segue to a page but this puts me outside the `UIPageView`. I would like the solution to be expandable, in that it does not segue to a specific page (with `pageViewController.setViewControllers` for example) but just allows the UIPageViewController to transition to the next/previous page.

Here is how I am intercepting the gesture currently.

```
    var leftScreenPanGestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleMapSwipe(_:)))
    leftScreenPanGestureRecognizer.edges = .Left
    leftScreenPanGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = true
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftScreenPanGestureRecognizer)
    self.webView.addGestureRecognizer(leftScreenPanGestureRecognizer)


    if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let lat = location.latitude
        let long = location.longitude
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/maps/place/\(lat),\(long)/")!))
    } else {
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/maps/")!))
    }
```

**Question is:** How to allow the UIPageViewController to intercept only the relevant gestures. Or to intercept the gesture then pass it to the UIPageViewController in an expandable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to handle this in an expandable way after learning about `self.parentViewController`

```
@IBAction func handleMapBackwardSwipe(recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    if (recognizer.state == .Began) {
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    } else if(recognizer.state == .Ended || recognizer.state == .Cancelled){
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    }

    // PageViewController is the controlling class for the UIPageViewController on the storyboard.
    let pvc = (self.parentViewController as! PageViewController)
    let newView = pvc.pageViewController(pvc, viewControllerBeforeViewController: self)
    if let newView = newView {
        pvc.setViewControllers([newView], direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func handleMapForwardSwipe(recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    if (recognizer.state == .Began) {
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    } else if(recognizer.state == .Ended || recognizer.state == .Cancelled){
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    }

    let pvc = (self.parentViewController as! PageViewController)
    let newView = pvc.pageViewController(pvc, viewControllerAfterViewController: self)
    if let newView = newView {
        pvc.setViewControllers([newView], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```